# How to perform multiplication of a column value row wise with another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe like this [image]. And I have to multiply the 'Factor' column value row wise with another dataframe  [image]

---

I want result like this

[image]

I have tried with df.mul. But it is giving me all NAN values. How to get this resultant matrix using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.to_numpy() * df1.to_numpy())
```

Comment: I think it is much more faster than apply

Comment: Yes,this is the better way. I'd be curious why he is getting nan values with my solution, i tested it and it worked

Comment: @Rabinzel and I test your sol for benchmark and it was ok

Answer (score 1):

```
df2.apply(lambda x: x * df1['factor'])
```

Comment: Getting NAN values.